# Mageplaza products slider items not updating

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, third-party-plugin

I'm using the products carousel via the shortcode method: https://docs.mageplaza.com/product-slider-m2/#cms-page-cms-static-block

I was wondering what settings there are available that I can add on here? e.g: I'd like to show 2 `.owl-item` divs, how can I do this? I've tried changing: `products_count="2"` with little luck, it still shows by default 3 items, I want to show say 4 items at any one time and then I can scroll. My shortcode is:

```
{{block class="Mageplaza\Productslider\Block\CategoryId" template="Mageplaza_Productslider::productslider.phtml" products_count="2" heading="Products carousel" category_id="3, 5" description="Products carousel"}}
```

I guess I need to somehow use: **Max Items Slider** as a setting on my shortcode to choose how many items display at different viewports

I've tried setting `items="4"` however I still get the default 3 shown. It appears this option isn't working?

Does anyone else have this issue?

I'm using Magento 2.2.7